# Update XML metadata in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, xml, xquery

I'm trying to change the value in the XML metadata using SQL Server.
The XML file looks like this:

```
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="MyOldValue">
<SomeTag></SomeTag>
```

What I want to do is to change xmlns to a new value. I tried casting the xml as nvarchar(max), using replace and then casting back to xml but it didn't work (string truncation).

I tried using XQuery but I kept failing. Can you recommend a solution?

Comment: What happens if you `CAST` the xml as `nvarchar(max)` and then back to `xml` *without* making any changes. Does this also give you a string truncation error? Also: is the SML file already stored in SQL, or are you loading it to do the conversion? and: where are you running the commands that give you the error"  SSMS? an SSIS package? or somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

I try this queries is ok.

```
DECLARE @xml XML='<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="MyOldValue"><SomeTag></SomeTag></Root>';

SELECT @xml = CAST( REPLACE(CAST(@xml AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),'MyOldValue','MyNewValue') AS XML);

Select @xml;
```